# Generic Constraint for allowing bitwise operations?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have an `enum` :

```
  public enum Flags {
        COMMAND_MSG = 1,
        COMMAND_FILE = 2,
        COMMAND_ACTION = 4,
      }
```

Now , suppose I set multiple values like :

```
Flags g = Flags.COMMAND_ACTION |Flags.COMMAND_MSG;
```

So I have an int with value `5`.

Now , from that `5` I want to see that it's a combination of  : `Flags.COMMAND_ACTION |Flags.COMMAND_MSG;`

*(**Notice** , I dont have `[Flags]`  attribute because I'm using protobuff library , and the enum is auto* generated.

What have I tried :

```
public string Show (Flags item)
{
  var s="";
  string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(Flags))
        .Cast<Flags>() 
        .Select(f=>(f & item) >0 ?f.ToString() :"") //check if bit is set
        .Where(f=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f))); //remove empty
  return s;
}
```

So `Show(5);` does display :  `COMMAND_MSG,COMMAND_ACTION`

*So where is the problem  ?*

I wanted to convert it to a generic extension method :

```
 public static string ToFlags<T>(this int val, T FlagType) where T : ??

    {
        return string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
                     .Cast<T>()
                     .Select(enumEntry => (enumEntry & val) > 0 ? enumEntry.ToString() : "")
                     .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f)));
    }
```

But there's an error because :

[image]

**Question :**

Which generic constraint should I apply in order for this to work ?

Comment: Related but not entirely a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172370/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-system-enum-and-system-enu

Comment: Have you tried `flagItem.ToString()`?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes `[Flags]` attribute takes care of the nice `ToString`  display , but as I said, I don't have this Attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no appropriate generic type constraint for this situation. You can apply bitwise operations to `int`s, so convert the enum value to int. `T` cannot be cast to `int` directly; however, you can make the detour over `object`.

```cs
public static string ToFlags<T>(this T val)
    where T : struct
{
    return string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>()
        .Select(enumEntry => ((int)(object)enumEntry & (int)(object)val) > 0
            ? enumEntry.ToString() : "")
        .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f)));
}
```

Note: There is a similar situation with numbers. You can't say `where T : number` and apply numeric operators on values of type T. *(See my update below)*

Also you can make `val` a `T` and you don't have to pass the type of `T` as method argument. You are passing it as generic type argument already. This is sufficient. The compiler is also smart enough to infer `T`, so you don't have to specify it when calling the method.

```cs
// Test
Flags item = Flags.COMMAND_ACTION | Flags.COMMAND_MSG;
Console.WriteLine(item.ToFlags());
```

You can specify `struct` as generic type constraint, as `struct` stands for value types. It is not perfect, but better than no constraint at all.

---

**Update**

A long time has passed since this question has been asked. C# 11 introduced [static virtual members in interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members) and the .NET 7 BCL the interfaces [IBitwiseOperators<T, T, T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.ibitwiseoperators-3) and [IEqualityOperators<T, T, bool>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iequalityoperators-3). These interfaces ([and many others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics)) are implemented for numeric types but unfortunately not for enums.

See: [[API Proposal]: Enum should implement IBitwiseOperators, IEqualityOperators #81664](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/81664).

Since C# 7.3 there is an [Enum generic constraint](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/#the-enum-constraint) that can be specified in addition to `struct`.

Comment: The cast from a generic parameter type to `int` should be flagged by the compiler as an error. Does this really work for you?

Comment: I changed it. You can fool the compiler by first casting to `object`.

Comment: Note that this will fail for enumerations with an underlying type other than `int`: it will then cause an `InvalidCastException`. But if the enumeration is known in advance to have an underlying type of `int`, this is a good approach.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `.ToFlags(default(Flags))`, or get rid of your `FlagType` parameter and write `.ToFlags<Flags>()`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no constraint you can use to allow any particular operator. .NET just isn't designed like that.

However, you don't need that. Instead of checking `(enumEntry & val) > 0`, you can use [`Enum.HasFlag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
((Enum)enumEntry).HasFlag((Enum)Enum.ToObject(enumEntry.GetType(), val))
```

Yes, admittedly, this looks quite ugly.

Comment: That's fine, but it only allows you to check the flag. How does one go about setting it? If I have enumEntry1 and enumEntry2, I should be able to get enumEntry1 | enumEntry2, but there is no ".SetFlag()" method...

Answer (score 2):

This works as intended:

```
    public static string ToFlags<T>(this int val) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        return string.Join(",", Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<T, int>(x, Convert.ToInt32(x)))
            .Select(kv => (kv.Value & val) > 0 ? kv.Key.ToString() : "")
            .Where(f => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(f)));
    }
```

1. I don't see the need for the extra parameter to the function.
2. The closest restriction to Enum i can come up with is struct, IConvertible

Comment: C# 7.3 adds support for `where T : Enum` which is a slight improvement, but still doesn't allow the use of bitwise operations without an ugly `(Int64)(Object)` cast.