# Adding extension methods for all enums, not just a specific kind

Tags: c#, generics, enums, constraints, extension-methods

**Edit**: This post is not a duplicate, those other solutions do not work in allowing me to use the bitwise operators.

I want to do something like this:

```
public static class EnumExt
{
    public static enum AddFlag(this enum e, enum flag) => e |= flag;
}
```

So I can use it like this:

```
Color color = Red;
color.AddFlag(Color.Dark);
```

It's just a bit easier to read. And **I want this single method to work for all enum values, instead of making an override for each one I plan on working with.** Problem is, that code won't work because `enum` isn't a type like `int` is. I tried doing something with generics:

```
public static class EnumExt
{
    public static T AddFlag<T>(this T e, T flag) 
        where T : Enum      // Can't constrain to Enum
    {
        return e = e | flag;
    }
}
```

and this:

```
public static T AddFlag<T>(this T e, T flag) 
    where T : struct
{
    if (!(typeof(T).IsEnum)) return default; 

    return e |= flag;      // Operator '|' cannot be applied to T
}
```

Which has two problems. Because it's a `struct` this means this method will show up for `int` values. I'm using `struct` only because it's the closest constraint to `Enum`. I exit the method if it's not an `Enum`, but that still doesn't let the compiler know that `e` is an `enum`, even though it should always be at this point.

Also tried using `where T : int` and using casting, but `int` is an invalid constraint.

Is there anyway this can be done?

**EDIT**: I have tried the two answers that have been suggested as solving the problem, but they do not. The one with `IEnumConstraint` doesn't work because it says my `enum` does not inherit from it, and neither of the answer allows me to actually do `return e |= flag;`

```
// Doesn't work because C# won't allow bitwise operators on generic types 
// Because the constraint is still vague enough for non-enum values to slip through
public static T AddFlag<T>(this T e, T flag)
    where T : struct, IConvertible

// Doesn't work because enums don't inherit from IEnumConstraint
// Same as above
public static T AddFlag<T>(this T e, T flag)
    where T : struct, IEnumConstraint
```

My guess is that, even if these did limit to only `Enum` values, it is still possible for some other class to inherit from `IEnumConstraint` and `IConvertible` therefore the bitwise operators won't work because it's still not a guarantee that operation will be available for `T`.

It seems the only real solution is in C# 7.3, where they allow you to use `System.Enum` as a constraint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Generic method constraining T to an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#enum-constraints

Comment: What version of VS 2017 do you have installed? Is it the latest preview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone know a good workaround for the lack of an enum generic constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244/anyone-know-a-good-workaround-for-the-lack-of-an-enum-generic-constraint)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/27657447/34092 help?

Comment: "It's just a bit easier to read" - except for anyone *familiar* with the C# language who'll be wondering why the second line of your example isn't just `color = color | Color.Dark` - i.e. the *standard* way of doing this and *not any longer to type*.

Comment: Funny, because when I see `color = color | Color.Dark` I'm wondering why it isn't just `color |= Color.Dark`.

Comment: Ah, did you already try? I feel like that defeats a bit of the point. I mean, at least it'll prevent other people from throwing in the wrong type and me having to throw an exception. Am I at least able to cast directly to `int` wihtout having to go through `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure it out. I have to cast from `T` to `object` then to `int`, use the bitwise operators on the `int` values, then reverse it to get the result back.

@mjwills pointed out that C# 7.3 won't be fixing the issue of casting. All it'll fix is the constraint and I'll be able to remove the throw exception.

```
public static T AddFlag<T>(this ref T e, T flag)
    where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!(typeof(T).IsEnum)) throw new ArgumentException("Value must be an enum");

    int added = (int)(object)e | (int)(object)flag;

    e = (T)(object)added;

    return e;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible improvement to [AustinWBryan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50363461/3030793) is:

```
internal static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDefinedAndNotDefault<T>(this T value)
        where T : Enum
    {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value) && !value.Equals(default(T));
    }
}
```